# Is there a way to simplify this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, simplify

I know this is a broad question but I'm still novice to know what to search/ask for.

I have this JavaScript series for a Jeopardy game. I am sure that there is a better way to do this because there is so much repetition. I'm thinking something with some variables, arrays, and/or passing IDs through when the function is called but don't know where to start. Any ideas would be appreciated. I am not asking anyone to do the work, just give me some ideas and examples of which direction to go.

```
var score = 0;


//Disable the question button
function disableButton(btnID){
        document.getElementById(btnID.id).disabled = true;
    }

//Show current score
function endQuestion(){
  alert ("Your total score is now " +score);
}

//Toggle Images On
function showImgBtn1(){
  document.getElementById('btn1pic').style.visibility = 'visible';
  setTimeout(askQuestion1,3000);
}
function showImgBtn2(){
  document.getElementById('btn2pic').style.visibility = 'visible';
  setTimeout(askQuestion2,3000);
}
//This keeps going for every question--repeated 9 to 20 times


//Questions
function askQuestion1()
{
  var answer = prompt ("What body system contains the heart, blood, arteries, and veins?") .toLowerCase();
   if (answer==="circulatory") {
    alert ("Correct!");
     score += 100;
  }
  else {
    alert ("Sorry, incorrect.");
     score -= 100;
  }
    endQuestion();
    document.getElementById('btn1pic').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function askQuestion2()
{
  var answer = prompt ("What body system contains the brain, spinal cord, and nerves?") .toLowerCase();
  if (answer==="nervous") {
   alert ("Correct!");
    score += 200;
  }
  else {
    alert ("Sorry, incorrect.");
    score -= 200;
  }
  endQuestion();
  document.getElementById('btn2pic').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
//This keeps going for every question--same code, just replace the question and answer repeated 9 to 20 times
```

This is how I call it on my HTML page:

```
<td><button id="btn1" onclick="showImgBtn1();disableButton(btn1)">100</button></td> //each button has a successive ID
```

and this is how I have the pics set up on my HTML page:

```
<div>
  <img class="picClue" id="btn1pic" src="btn1.jpg" height="200px">
  <img class="picClue" id="btn2pic" src="btn2.jpg" height="200px">
  <img class="picClue" id="btn3pic" src="btn3.jpg" height="200px">
  <img class="picClue" id="btn4pic" src="btn4.jpg" height="200px">
</div>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: _don't know where to start..._ Put all duplicate code into one function - Start with : `showImgBtn(button, askQuestion, duration)` - Then do this in a similar way with `askQuestion(questionId)` and so on..

Comment: start with the data. I think a quiz is is an ordered (?) list of picture+question+correct answer. think of your function(s) to render your page to take that as an input.
Also, if you want to make a serious quiz - don't send the answers to the client :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a few things that you could improve. It is a good things that you notice there is a lot of repetition in your code. First of all, the function `askQuestion1` and `askQuestion2` does the exact same thing with the exception of a few variable. So you could make one function and store your different value into a object. Something like this :

```js
let values = {
  question1: {
    questionText: "What body system contains the heart, blood, arteries, and veins?",
    correctValue: "circulatory",
    id: 'btn1pic'
  },
  question2: {
    questionText: "What body system contains the brain, spinal cord, and nerves?",
    correctValue: "nervous",
    id: 'btn2pic'
  }
}

let score = 0;

function askQuestion(question)
{
  var answer = prompt(question.questionText);
   // validate null and check if the answer is correct.
   if (answer && answer.toLowerCase() === question.correctValue) {
    alert ("Correct!");
     score += 100;
  }
  else {
    alert ("Sorry, incorrect.");
     score -= 100;
  }
    endQuestion();
    document.getElementById(question.id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function endQuestion() {}

askQuestion(values.question1);
askQuestion(values.question2);
```

as [Edric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782707/edric) pointed out in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376354/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-this-javascript-code/59376522#comment104945353_59376522), it is a good idea to validate that your user did not cancel the prompt, resulting in a null value in your `answer` variable.

You could even save your question in an array and use a `for` loop to ask each of them:

```
    let values = [
      {
        questionText: "What body system contains the heart, blood, arteries, and veins?",
        correctValue: "circulatory",
        id: 'btn1pic'
      },
      {
        questionText: "What body system contains the brain, spinal cord, and nerves?",
        correctValue: "nervous",
        id: 'btn2pic'
      }
    ]
/* ... */
    for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i ++) {
        askQuestion(values[i]);
    }
```

The same things goes for your `showImgBtn` function, having a question variable would create less repetition.

```js
//Toggle Images On
function showImgBtn(question){
  document.getElementById(question.id).style.visibility = 'visible';
  setTimeout(() => { askQuestion(question); },3000);
}
```

Other than that, it seams fine.

I highly encourage you to check the comment aswell, many people are suggesting ways to improve my answer.

Comment: You didn't consider that the user might cancel the prompt that would be shown, which would result in an error where you're calling `toLowerCase` on a `null` result.

Comment: Since this is jeopardy I would add `questionScore` as an attribute to each question in `values`.

Comment: That's correct @Edric However, i tried to stick to OP's code But i will edit my answer.

Comment: `for(let value of values) askQuestion(value)`

Comment: `values.forEach(askQuestion)` ... `setTimeout(askQuestion, 3000, question)` ...

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas I see what you're talking about and will work on it. I am having trouble with passing the data from HTML to JavaScript but think I have something typed wrong somewhere. Thanks to the other commenters too. Great ideas all around.

Comment: @Nicolas I have gone through and truly do understand what you have shown me. However, once the argument gets passed into the function, it isn't being seen as a variable anymore. I inserted some console.log( ) in the code to see what is happening and console.log(question); returns the proper value passed into the function but then console.log(question.questionText) returns as undefined. I even tried adding "values.question.questionText" and it was a different error about properties. Am I missing something to make the variable continue through and not be seen as a string?

Comment: How do you call the function ? @BillPratt

Comment: @Nicolas I am using the following button with an onclick 
```<td><button id="btn1" onclick="showImgBtn('question1');disableButton('btn1')">100</button></td>```

Comment: The ;`showImgBtn`  does not take a string as argument but a question object: `showImgBtn(values[0])`

Comment: but if you're calling that from your HTML, you might not have access to the `values` varaible. So you could use another function that would take a string and call the coresponding question object. `function(key) { showImgBtn(values[key]); };`

Comment: @Nicolas Worked perfectly! Thank you. I had to add a name to the function (key) that you had so I used onclick="startQuestion('question1')" and made it function startQuestion(key). Thanks so much. I have a couple of schools worth of kids that will love to do this!